# Automorphism with zero trace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a commutative field with characteristic different from $2$

and $E$ be a $K$-vector space with dimension $n>1$

What are the automorphism in $E$ that are written as product of automorphism with zero trace ?

Comment: Is that specifically a product of *two* zero trace automorphisms?

Comment: not necessarly , (for any product)

Answer (score 0):

For $n=2$ I used that $Gln(K)$ is generated by transvections and dilatations than all transvections and dilataions are products of automorphism with zero trace , for a generalisation maybe we should try induction , I'll be glad to see a solution for the generalisation

Answer (score 0):

For general $n$: the usual generating set is that of the "elementary matrices" from row-reduction.  In particular, it suffices to show that we reach every element of the form
$$
D = \pmatrix{\alpha\\&I_{n-1}}, \qquad E = \pmatrix{1\\\alpha & 1\\
&&I_{n-2}}
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Then note that if $A_1A_2\cdots A_k = E$, then $(PA_kP^{-1})(PA_kP^{-1})\cdots(PA_kP^{-1}) = PEP^{-1}$, where $P$ is an appropriate permutation similarity and the $A_i$ are trace free.

Getting the dilation $D$ is relatively straightforward.  Take
$$
D = \pmatrix{0&\alpha\\I_{n-1}&0} \pmatrix{0&I_{n-1}\\ 1 & 0}
$$
(note: the matrices are not conformally partitioned).  I'm not sure how to get $E$ (our generalized transvection).